# Excel formula to sum values in a column up to a specified value, but only sum numbers which have a specified value in the column next to them as well

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a data set in which I have 2 sheets, one sheet holds a list of names with a large value alongside them. On the second sheet there is a second list of names with values however these are much smaller.

Some combination of the values on the second page come to a total of the value on the first page and I am looking to write a formula on the first page next to each row which will look for the name on the second sheet and sum all the values on the second sheet (providing they have the correct name next to them) to reach the value next to the name on the first sheet.

I have included some example data below to hopefully make that less confusing;

[image: example data]

Hopefully that makes sense but happy to clarify anything, essentially looking to have a formula in D3,4,5,6 which sums the values in H3:H18 provided they have the corresponding name next to them, but only to reach the value in C column for each row, for example adding H3, H4 and H5 to equal D3 but excluding H6 as it goes over the total.

Comment: If you just need to total the value until the next value will "push it over the limit" - then you could use Filter to generate a range and pass that to a recursive lamda to add up until the limit is met.  But you may want to know which combination will add up to the desired value - which is a different answer.

Comment: what should be the result of 26, 50, 25, 25 with a limit of 100?

Comment: Thank you for the replies I appreciate all the help, I have replied in more detail to another user who posted an answer but I am currently looking for it to determine which combination add up to the desired value and give that as an exact result rather than adding up until it would go over the limit.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? **[Look Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/mPxZJaj)** and let me know

Comment: That is almost exactly what I'm looking for thank you! Is there a way that I can either have an additional formula to sum the numbers displayed in text from the formula you have written, or alter the formula to display the numbers added together rather than separated? (Ie instead of showing "25, 50, 25" it shows "100" or have another formula which is able to total the numbers within the cell separated by commas?)

Comment: Refer this and let me know, should resolve this now: **[Look Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/slx6pUt)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, and after going through the comments in the OP, then the following formula should be suffice to accomplish the desired output.

The following formulas shown below, works with `MS365` and uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function called `SCAN()` and if one needs to return the whole output using one single dynamic array formula then can use `MAKEARRAY()`.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, FILTER($H$3:$H$18,(B3=$G$3:$G$18)),
     δ, TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(α,SCAN(0,α,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))<=C3)),
     HSTACK(δ,SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(δ,", "))))
```

---

- `α` --> Returns the value range from `Sheet 2` by matching `Name` in `Sheet 1` with `Name` in `Sheet 2`
- `δ` --> Returns a delimited list by doing a `LAMBDA()` iteration using `SCAN()` function to get a running total of `α` based on each names, and using `FILTER()` to extract those which are less than equal to `C3` i.e. `Value` in `Sheet 1`.
- Lastly, using `TEXTSPLIT()` to split the above variable & sum the same, as well merge together to form a `1x2` array using `HSTACK()` to return the output.

---

The above formula needs to fill down, while the following formula will spill for the whole array.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D3</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B3:C6),2, LAMBDA(r,c,
 INDEX(LET(α, FILTER(H3:H18,(INDEX(B3:B6,r)=G3:G18)),
           δ, TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(α,SCAN(0,α,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))<=INDEX(C3:C6,r))),
           HSTACK(δ,SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(δ,", ")))),c)))
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate the explanation you have given as well as a lot of this function is beyond my normal capabilities when it comes to excel formula, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Comment: @dixoa004 the first approach explains all, the second one, is only used to return as a single dynamic array solution, where you dont have to take the pain in filling down, `MAKEARRAY()` will iterate over those functions using those `INDEX()`s with `r` and `c` for respective cells and perform the calculations. Rest remains same. That is way try to understand the first one by stepping one by one, you will get hold of it. Once you know the logic you have a win-win situation. Thanks glad it helped and worked for you!